# If I have an object , a method name in a string and method takes one parameter, how can I call the method?

Tags: python

How am I supposet to call `bar2` using `getattr`, considering that it has a parameter `para`?

```
class Foo:
    def bar1(self):
        print 1
    
    def bar2(self, para):
        print 2

f = Foo()
getattr(f, "bar1")  # 1
getattr(f, ???)
```

Comment: `getattr(f, "bar2")(arg)` — Your example does *not* print 1 BTW, since you’re not calling `bar1`.

Answer (score 0):

This code does the trick

```
class Foo:
    def bar1(self):
        print (1)
    
    def bar2(self, para):
        print (para)

f = Foo()
getattr(f, "bar1")
getattr(f,"bar2")("name")
```